# Calculate rate of Columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table like below.I also keep a variable in the Oracle package to use in the table below.

For example : q_value = 27;

For each piece column by grouping the table,I want to do this calculation
q_value * ((piece_value)/(all_piece_values))

FOR 2111TN IS RATE VALUE:27*/(658)/(658+388))

FOR 2112TN IS RATE VALUE:27*/(388)/(658+388))

| PIECE | MPIECE | PART | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2111TN | 2110HB | 1 | 658 |
| 2111TN | 2110HB | 1 | 658 |
| 2112TN | 2110HB | 2 | 388 |
| 2112TN | 2110HB | 2 | 388 |

so the result of the query is for me ,should be as follows :

| PIECE | MPIECE | PART | VALUE | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2111TN | 2110HB | 1 | 658 | 17 |
| 2112TN | 2110HB | 2 | 388 | 10 |

How should I create a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any other way here rather than using analytical function

```
select piece, mpiece, part, value,
       round(27 * value/(sum(value) over())) rate
  from some_table
 group by piece, mpiece, part, value
```